# What's the reason of using tt2 extension vs tt for template toolkit?

Tags: templates, template-toolkit

I'm reading a tutorial and one of the first thing it mentions is to use the `tt2` extension  instead of `tt` for template toolkit files.  What's the reason?

Comment: Where are you reading that?

Comment: Catalyst tutorial - http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/Catalyst-Manual-5.9003/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial/03_MoreCatalystBasics.pod#Configure_HTML.pm_For_The_Wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now realize what a dumb question this is.  The latest version of TT is version 2. Hence, the extension should read tt2. Plain and simple :).